# can't initialize backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm learning backbone.js and already have a problem.

I'm loading my scripts with LABjs like this:

```
$LAB.setOptions({BasePath : path})
.script('libs/underscore.js?v=1.3.3')
.script('libs/backbone.js?v=0.9.2')
.script('libs/jquery.js?v=1.7')
.script('libs/bootstrap.min.js?v=2.0.2').wait()
.script('test.js');
```

In my test.js I have this (from backbonetutorials.com):

```
(function($){
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        alert("Alerts suck.");
    }
});

var search_view = new SearchView;
})(jQuery);
```

As you see this should give me an alert with text "Alerst suck.". 
Instead it throws an error on my firebug console - `i is not a function` (34 line of backbone.js).

If I try to initialize view like this `var search_view = new SearchView({el: $('#some_dom_element')});` it gives me another error -  `invalid 'instanceof' operand i` (34 line of backbone.js file).

jQuery object `$` is defined.
I can initialize Backbone.js models without any problems. Just view throws those errors. What I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that order in which scripts are loaded **matters**. I've loaded jQuery first now and it started to work. I've also tested it with non minified version of backbone.js and the error was more verbose `$ is not a function`. So again - loading jQuery before backbone.js fixed it.

**EDIT**: When loading jQuery after backbone.js when I do `console.log($)` right before view initialization it shows tha $ is a **function**. Why backbone.js fails to work then? Can someone explain this?